# Vba change selected rows on worksheet with a userform button

Tags: vba, excel, button, listbox

I made a userform containing received phonecalls during a day. 
When a button is clicked the status of the selected rows needs to be changed to finished on the worksheet and the listbox. 
I managed to change the listbox but not the sourcerow on the worksheet.

Can you help me?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim lItem As Long
Dim row As Integer
Dim col As Integer

col = 5

    For lItem = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(lItem) Then

                With ListBox1
                    row = .ListIndex
                    .List(row, col) = "Finished"

                End With

        End If
    Next lItem

End Sub


Private Sub showdata_Click()

ListBox1.RowSource = ""
Dim j As Byte



For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"))

If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "E").Value = comselectnaam.Value And 
(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "F").Value = "Not started" Or ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 
 "F").Value = "In progress") Then

        With ListBox1
            .AddItem
            .List(j, 0) = Cells(i, 1)
            .List(j, 1) = Cells(i, 2)
            .List(j, 2) = Cells(i, 3)
            .List(j, 3) = Cells(i, 4)
            .List(j, 4) = Cells(i, 5)
            .List(j, 5) = Cells(i, 6)
            j = j + 1
        End With

   End If
 Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: Can there be a selected cell in the row when you click the button?  If so a target is generated upon selection change, you can pass the target (targ) to your function and get the row and act upon it.  Otherwise you can use a unique identifier from the row like ticket# or phone number and search the rows on the appropriate column.  How are you populating the list box, would help to see that code as well.

Comment: I see the code now. Looks like the row number is variable "i" and I don't see it passed in or declared, so it is in another function in the module, form,  or worksheet? You are filling the list with column items from the same row, I don't see j initialized.  I will post some code below.

Comment: were you able to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you loaded your list equal to the row, no offset? Again I don't get to see what j is only the incrementing.  Why is j a byte?  i starts at 2 and you should really find the lastrow logic rather that what I see you doing here in my opinion.  Is there a relationship between j and i, I have code where the list is loaded with the same integer i as is used to reference the spreadsheet row, here it is, a 4 column listbox built referencing a spreadhseet who's name is Datasheet, all references to col and row are doubles (like LastRow and i)

```
'Lat row logic only shown here for context, here using col one as reference
LastRow = DATAsheet.Cells(DATAsheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' count rows based on ID columns

With Me.ListBox2
    .Clear 'clear to set up the list
    .ColumnCount = 4
    .ColumnWidths = "60;70;65;150"
    For i = 0 To LastRow - 2 'data starts in Row2 i is now out of sync by 2 with spreadsheet rows account for this below
        If LastRow >= 2 Then 'data starts in row two
            .AddItem
            .List(i, 0) = DATAsheet.Cells(i + 2, 1) 'Column of the ID, data starts in row 2
            .List(i, 1) = DATAsheet.Cells(i + 2, 4) 'Column of the Date, data starts in row 2
            .List(i, 2) = DATAsheet.Cells(i + 2, 2) ' Column of motor Size, data starts in row 2
            .List(i, 3) = DATAsheet.Cells(i + 2, 3) ' Column of motor SN, data starts in row 2
        Else ' Do nothing
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Since you now now the list to row offset is 2 for the code above, I would use it in your code as follows (yours may be different, what is the relationship between j and i?)

```
For lItem = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(lItem) Then 'a list item is selected
                    'offset that list item row number by spreadsheet row reference, you know this from building the list
                    selRow = lItem + 2 'selRow avoid anything that looks reserved like row
'you are changing the spreadsheet value, not the list column value, if you are you need a two point index to change the list item
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(selRow, "F").Value = "Finished"

        End If
 Next lItem
```

Are you trying to change the reported status on the worksheet or are you trying to change the reported status in the listbox?  If the worksheet then the listbox will change next time you load it this way.

I also strongly recommend that you get away from activesheet unless you only have one sheet in the workbook and tend to only have one workbook open at a time.  If not you will run into trouble.  How to do this?  You can put all your Dims at the top of the module and they will scope to only that module, form, or worksheet depending on the container.  If you find you are declaring multiple times in private subs.

```
'top of module
Option Explicit
Dim statusWS as Worksheet

'In your code or set a function to intitialize this modules variables when you have a lot of them
Set statusWS = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("yourworksheetname")
'replace all of your activesheet with statusWS
```

I hope this helps.
Cheers, Wookie